# Chrome Remote Desktop Authorize Permission

Tags: google-chrome, permissions, remote-desktop

I installed Chrome Remote Desktop on Chrome browser (I use debian 8) then signed in but it stuck at "Get started" page. An "Authorize" message pops up saying:

> "To continue you must first grant extended access permissions. You
>   only have to do this once."

I push continue, but the message persists. Yet it asks me to login and choose my account. I choose my account, but another message shows up saying:

> You are not signed in to chrome. Please sign in and try again.

I can't go further "Get started" page and choose other devices. Any solution?